# Trouble assigning a string to dynamic array location

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-arrays, assign

I am getting an error of "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when trying to add a string to a dynamic array. Am I doing something wrong? Here is some snippets of code:

```
typedef unsigned short ushort_t;
typedef string* stringPtr_t;

class Doctor {
private:
    string doctorName;
    stringPtr_t patientArray;
    ushort_t patientArraySize;
    ushort_t numOfPatient;    

    bool Doctor::addPatient(string patientName) 
    {
        patientArray[numOfPatient].assign(patientName);
        numOfPatient++;
        return true;
    }

    Doctor& Doctor::operator =(const Doctor& docSource) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < docSource.patientArraySize; i++) {
            patientArray[i].assign(docSource.patientArray[i]);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Doctor testDoc5(2);
    cout.clear();
    assert(testDoc5.addPatient("Bob Smith")==true);
}

Doctor::Doctor(ushort_t patientArrayCapacity) 
    : doctorName("need a name.")
    , patientArraySize(patientArrayCapacity)
    , numOfPatient(0) 
{
    patientArray = *new stringPtr_t[patientArraySize]; 
}
```

Comment: Where is patientArray assigned to?

Comment: Did you allocate any memory for patientArray?

Comment: @Mark it is assigned to a previosuly constructed Doctor Object I will edit to show this.

Comment: Why = *new what is wrong with just = new in the patientArray?

Comment: use `std::vector` if you can.

Comment: @Mark xcode is telling me I have to have it because it is a pointer.

Comment: @user3373291 do `patientArray = new std::string[patientArraySize];`

Comment: Do you want `patientArray` to be a pointer to an array of strings or to an array of string pointers? this line is suspect: `new stringPtr_t[patientArraySize]` because you're using `new` to instantiate a pointer type, not a `string`

Comment: @user3373291 - That's why std::vector was invented, so that you aren't writing code like this.  You have a memory leak, no user-defined copy constructor for Doctor, a bad assignment operator (you are not copying all of your members, etc.)

Comment: @user3373291 - Also, in your assignment operator, what if the object passed has more patients than the current object? You now have a memory overwrite error. All of this goes to show you that writing such classes that handle dynamically allocated memory *correctly* is not for beginners. It is so error-prone that even professionals don't do it if they don't have to -- instead they use std::vector and other container classes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie unfortunately for the assignment I have to do it without std::vector

Answer (score 0):

The suspect line is:

```
patientArray = *new stringPtr_t[patientArraySize];
```

Let's examine this in a little more detail.

Expanding (replacing typedefs) results in

```
patientArray = * new string * [patientArraySize];
```

Looking at the allocation part:

```
new string * [patientArraySize];
```

Allocates an array of pointers to strings.  This may not be what you want.

The next part:

```
* (new string * [patientArraySize]);
```

dereferences the pointer to the array of strings, thus referring  to the first element of the array.

And lastly, the assignment:

```
patientArray = * (new string * [patientArraySize]);
```

Assigns the contents of array location zero to your variable `patientArray`.  This is legal since you told the compiler you are allocating an array of **pointers** to strings.

Side effects:
1.  You have lost the location of the start of array.  Also known as a memory leak.
2.  The content of the `patientArray` pointer is undefined since you didn't initialize the pointer value in the first location of the array.

Maybe you want:

```
  patientArray = new string [patientArraySize];
```

which allocates an array of strings and assigns to your pointer `patientArray`.

This whole issue would go away if you used `std::vector<string>(patientArraySize)`.